# How can I pass an any object to a function?

Tags: c++, object, types

I am trying to pass an any object to a function (to check its type), and I have something like this:

```
void Write(Object obj)
{
    cout << typeid(obj).name() << endl;
}
```

But i got an error 'Write' was not declared in this scope.
I assume that there is no an 'Object' type

Comment: No, there's no such thing like a general `Object` type in standard c++. The closest you can get is `std::any`.

Comment: `template <typename T> void Write(const T& obj) { std::cout << typeid(obj).name() << std::endl; }`?

Comment: You are confusing C++ with another language. Checking an object's type is very rarely required in C++, and this is not the way to do it.

Comment: @Dean2690 that's an incredibly bad idea.

Comment: I think you would benefit from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  Don't assume that C++ is like that other curly-brace language you're familiar with.

Comment: if there was such a monster base class you'd need to pass by reference not by value. But who would built such a monster base class into a language ? ... oh wait...

Comment: If the intent is for human-readable output, you might want to [`demangle`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/demangle.html) the name.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is not Java. There is not an `Object` class that every other class inherits from. You can use a template, but you still won't have the same kind of runtime introspection in C++.

```
template <class Object>
void Write(Object obj) {
    std::cout << ... << std::endl;
}
```

As noted in a comment, you probably want to pass the argument by const reference, rather than value.

```
template <class Object>
void Write(const Object& obj) {
    std::cout << ... << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: should probably be `const Object&`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you can use `auto` to let the compiler figure out the type. This means if you pass an `int`, `auto` results in the `int` type. This is the closest, in terms of syntax, you will get to having an "any" type.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d7YPrhT4r):

```
void Write(auto obj){
    std::cout << typeid(obj).name() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Write(int{});
}
```

output:

```
int
```

---

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice.

Comment: worth noting that this is actually a template and each function instantiated from it will still take one type